# How to restrict filetype for Dropbox Chooser

Tags: javascript, dropbox

How do I restrict Dropbox Chooser to let the user select only pictures and videos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the options you can specify e.g.:

```
extensions: ['.pdf', '.doc', '.docx', '.jpg', '.gif', '.png']
```

Answer (score 0):

The Chooser doesn't currently support restricting the file type.

**EDIT:** My answer is out-of-date. See @deyen's answer.